# Expand C# VS snippet on the same line

Tags: visual-studio, code-snippets

When using custom snippets, VS always seems to expand the snippet on the next line, creating an empty line which is unwanted.

How can I prevent this?

---

## Example

A custom snippet:

```xml
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
<Header>
  <SnippetTypes>
    <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
  </SnippetTypes>
  <Title>Argument not null check</Title>
  <Shortcut>an</Shortcut>
</Header>
<Snippet>
  <Declarations>
    <Literal Editable="true">
      <ID>argument</ID>
      <ToolTip>Argument name</ToolTip>
      <Default>arg</Default>
    </Literal>
  </Declarations>
  <Code Language="csharp" Kind="method body" Delimiter="$"><![CDATA[if ($argument$ == null)
throw new ArgumentNullException("$argument$");]]></Code>
</Snippet>
</CodeSnippet>
```

How I would expect (and like) the snippets to work:

```cs
public void Concat(string a, string b)
{
    an
    an

    return a + b;
}
...
public void Concat(string a, string b)
{
    if (a == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("a");
    if (b == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("b");

    return a + b;
}
```

How it actually works:

```cs
public void Concat(string a, string b)
{

    if (a == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("a");

    if (b == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("b");

    return a + b;
}
```

The weird thing is that the CodeContract snippets work as expected, but comparing the xml I can't see how they are different, even when I am using a single line custom snippet.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and did some testing. It seems that Visual Studio 2015 inserts a blank line when the code snippet doesn't contain an `$end$` marker. If you insert an `$end$` marker at the end of your CDATA section inside your `<Code>` tag, Visual Studio will stop prepending a blank line at the beginning of your snippet.

Seems like a bug to me. Visual Studio 2013 didn't have this problem.